# Accessing AngularJS model objects via an array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got an interesting problem (to me at least).

I'm on a project where we are getting data from an API and its nesting a set of objects in an array.  We want to be able to display/edit them individually.  The tricky part is getting to them from the view.  Here's the setup using a similar but made up scenario.

User navigates to /profile/exploit/1

Ideally we grab that parameter and use it to filter the array.  Here's the sample JS (without the param, I'm hardcoding the value for simplicity)

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    // The data is coming in from the API in a similar format.
    // There is an array with objects in it, and we need 
    // display and/or edit those individual records
    // This is a way simplified version of it
    // (and nothing like the real data, haha)
    $scope.profile = {
      name: "Alexander",
      location: "Earth",
      exploits: [
        {name: "Conquer Achaemenid empire", year: "334 BC", duration: 3},
        {name: "Conquer the Balkans", year: "335 BC", duration: 4},
        {name: "Conquer the Persian Empire", year: "334 BC", duration: 6}
      ],
    }
    // I planned to set this with a parameter /profile/exploits/1
    e = 1;
  }]);
```

And, here's the HTML

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.16" data-semver="1.2.16" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
      Name: {{ profile.exploits[0].name }}<br/>
      Year: {{ profile.exploits[0].year }}<br/>
      Duration: {{ profile.exploits[0].duration }} months
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

What I'd like to do is something like:
    {{ profile.exploits[e].name }}

Where e sets the record in the array.  But I can't for the life of me figure out how to make that happen.  Seriously hoping it's something ridiculously simple.

I've got a mock of it here http://embed.plnkr.co/XhIlJt8BGCAkw70tRTgn/preview

Comment: Do you need all exploits in the view or only the first?

Comment: I'd like to be able to request any of them via params. For example if we need to show the second exploit they would view profile/exploit/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull info from the url with $location.  So try something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {

  $scope.profile = {
    name: "Alexander",
    location: "Earth",
    exploits: [
      {name: "Conquer Achaemenid empire", year: "334 BC", duration: 3},
      {name: "Conquer the Balkans", year: "335 BC", duration: 4},
      {name: "Conquer the Persian Empire", year: "334 BC", duration: 6}
    ],
  }

  $scope.activeProfile = function() {
    var i = $location.path();  //Should be your desired value
    return $scope.profile.exploits[i];
  }

}]);
```

Hope this helps,

Jordan

Comment: For some reason, It didn't even occur to me to use a function to do that.  I guess I just assumed that angular wouldn't want that.  Awesome Jordan.  It works, I need to do a few tweaks to the app, but it works. Thank you muchly!